# Itch.io games I downloaded aren't working

Tags: games

I downloaded two or three games off of Itch.io that supported Linux and no matter how many times I try to start them it tells me that there is no ":" in the uri and I don't know what to do but I hope this makes sense.

Comment: No this don't make much sense. Please tell the full error message. Screenshots would be helpful. Use [edit] to add additional information.

Comment: Which games are these? How did you install and launch them? Please edit to add more information.

Comment: They are called "Afternoon Spaghetti" and "Pet The Pup" and what I did is when I downloaded them I went to files and pressed on the game and then when it loaded I pressed the game to start up and it won't work (I'm getting pictures)

Comment: you have to be sure to have downloaded the linux version.

Comment: Yes I made sure to do that.